# add dropdowns to magento

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu

I would like to add dropdowns to the top navigation on a magento site, would this involve a plugin or is there built in functunality that could potentially do this already?

Comment: Are you referring simply to submenus on the top menu? If so, it's pretty default to most themes, just add some subcategories to your main categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to say based on your details, but if you are looking for *mostly* css menus I believe many of the free themes that come with magento have drop-down menus. Also, there are several free and paid extensions that have slightly different functionality from the stock themes.  Check them out by [searching Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/filter/all?query=navigation+dropdown).  One that I used before was [ExplodedMenu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Raptor+Commerce+%28toby%29/extension/1345/raptor_explodedmenu) (it also has a paid big brother, [SuperMenu](http://www.raptorcommerce.com/supermenu.html)), but your requirements aren't really that clear, so it is tough to say.

If you are talking about select-box dropdowns, I am not so sure.  You can certainly build your own extension, possibly starting with ExplodedMenu as a template.

Good luck. :)